# За какую ассимптотику работает std::stoi?

Tags: c++, строки

В связи с решением одной задачи, в которой я из - за `std::stoi` получила TL, мне стало интересно - за сколько эта функция работает (в плане ассимптотики). Хотя точные цифры тоже было бы неплохо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это замерить и какие есть похожие функции, я бы их тоже проверила.

Comment: O(n), где n количество символов (цифр) в строке

Comment: У Вас опечатки в тексте

Comment: @avp ясно. А константа какая? (как она вообще работает?)

Comment: @АняА., [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/?kw=stoi), пишут, что внутри для преобразований используется [strtol()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), [вот](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdlib/strtol.c) одна из ее реализаций (сами преобразования в функции [__intscanf()](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/intscan.c))

Comment: Алгоритм там (упрощенно) такой:  пропускаем whitespaces; анализируем знак; если аргумент base = 0 (основание системы счисления), то анализируем начало строки и устанавливаем base = 10 или 8 или 16; устанавливаем результат в 0; далее в цикле, пока очередной символ это цифра умножаем результат на base и прибавляем цифру. По ходу определяем переполнение. Определяем позицию, где остановились. Возвращаем результат.